# Dual output/dual input canceling 12v trigger

Tags: digital-logic, 12v, low-voltage

I have a video projector with two 12V trigger outputs (output impedance: 4.7 kilohms). It is attached to two separate motorized screens. Unfortunately the projector software makes the second trigger additive to the first, but I need them to operate exclusively.

So, I think need to construct a gate according to the following truth table:

```
| i1 | i2 | o1 | o2 |
|----|----|----|----| 
| F  | F  | F  | F  |
| T  | F  | T  | F  |
| F  | T  | F  | T  |
| T  | T  | F  | T  |
```

I don't remember any of my high school EE, but I can solder, so I would like a recommendation for a simple circuit to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I discovered I can also accomplish this by cross-wiring the outputs of this 2 channel relay board: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LW15F42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your O2 signal. It is identical to i2, so there is no need to do anything with it.

The O1 signal can be realized using a simple inverter and an AND gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flXgzO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want to build something like this, you'll probably not want to buy two chips for such a simple job. You can implement the same using NAND gates. A NAND gate with it's inputs connected works as an inverter. We use one of them to replace the inverter, and another to turn the NAND gate back into an AND gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYW3Vi.png)</sup>

If you want to build the circuit you'll find chips with four NAND gates in it as TL7400 (a classic, works with 5V, so you need voltage translation) or the CD4011 which will work fine from a 12V supply.

Comment: In the unlikely event somebody else is trying to build this:

  - It is possible to use i1 as the power supply (with the CD4011 at least)
  - I also had to add a 10k pulldown resistor on i2